# Unir três códigos similares em um só

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo, otimização

Estou trabalhando com uma tabela que mostra o número de vagas oferecidas, candidatos inscritos e ingressantes em cursos superiores. Quero fazer um programa que permita a visualização desses dados a partir do *input* do usuário (digamos que ele queira saber quantas vagas foram oferecidas e quantas pessoas entraram em cursos de Direito... ele digita "Direito" e o programa mostra esses números).

Consegui fazer os códigos funcionarem, mas só um por um, em três programas diferentes. Será que é possível unir esses três em um só código?

1)

```
import csv

curso_desejado = input('Qual o curso? ')
vagas = 0
arquivo = open('oks4c.csv', encoding='utf8')
for registro in csv.reader(arquivo):
    vagas_oferecidas = registro[1]
    curso = registro[0]
    if curso == curso_desejado:
        vagas += int(vagas_oferecidas)
print(f'O número de vagas oferecidas em {curso_desejado} é: {vagas}')
```

2)

```
import csv

curso_desejado = input('Qual o curso? ')
inscritos = 0
arquivo = open('oks4c.csv', encoding='utf8')
for registro in csv.reader(arquivo):
    candidatos_inscritos = registro[2]
    curso = registro[0]
    if curso == curso_desejado:
        inscritos += int(candidatos_inscritos)
print(f'O número de inscritos em {curso_desejado} é: {inscritos}')
```

3)

```
import csv

curso_desejado = input('Qual o curso? ')
ingressos = 0
arquivo = open('oks4c.csv', encoding='utf8')
for registro in csv.reader(arquivo):
    ingressantes = registro[3]
    curso = registro[0]
    if curso == curso_desejado:
        ingressos += int(ingressantes)
print(f'O número de ingressantes em {curso_desejado} é: {ingressos}')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seria basicamente isto:

```
import csv

curso_desejado = input('Qual o curso? ')
vagas = 0
inscritos = 0
ingressos = 0
arquivo = open('oks4c.csv', encoding='utf8')
for registro in csv.reader(arquivo):
    if registro[0] == curso_desejado:
        vagas += int(registro[1])
        inscritos += int(registro[2])
        ingressos += int(registro[3])
print(f'O número de vagas oferecidas em {curso_desejado} é: {vagas}')
print(f'O número de inscritos em {curso_desejado} é: {inscritos}')
print(f'O número de ingressantes em {curso_desejado} é: {ingressos}')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/FlattenAlgorithm.py)

Ou seja, peguei a parte que não muda e e adicionei as partes que mudam.

Tem como diminuir 6 linhas (embora vai acabar precisando de mais 3 ou até mais), mas acho que não compensa.

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou.

Aproveitando, seria viável fazer uma operação (a ser mostrada em uma quarta linha de print) mostrando que os X ingressos de tal curso representam que Y% do total de vagas oferecidas foi ocupado? Ou percentual em Python é complicado?

Comment: @Guilherme Percentual é simples em qualquer linguagem, basta saber aritmética. Isto é outro problema.

Comment: De fato, é um cálculo simples @Maniero! Pensei que precisaria fazer algum tipo de arranjo mais complicado. Mas fiquei na dúvida de onde colocar. Em que parte do código eu poderia inserir a linha
    `porcentagem = ingressos / vagas * 100`
ou melhor
    `porcentagem = int(ingressos / vagas) * 100`
para que, além do número de vagas, inscritos e ingressos, lá embaixo o programa mostrasse também o percentual de vagas preenchidas? Tentei usar esses comandos, mas a linha
    `print(f'O percentual de vagas preenchidas em {curso_desejado} é: {porcentagem}')` não mostra o resultado...